# name value list field is not generating in custom item generator base class

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I am generating a base class of my template through the Custom Item Generator in Sitecore. My template has a field of type "Name Value List". Other fields with types such as "single-line text", "multi-line text", "image", .etc, are generated in the C# **.base class code but the "Name value List" field is not. So please tell me how to generate a "name value list" field in the  **.base class.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `App_Config\Include\CustomItem.config` file there's a section that maps each Sitecore field to a corresponding C# wrapper class. The default config appears to not map a **Name Value List**. To remedy this:

1. Open the `App_Config\Include\CustomItem.config`
2. In the `<FieldMappings>` section add a new `<FieldMapping>` XML node
3. Map the "Name Value List" `fieldType` to what you believe to be the correct wrapper class, or define your own custom wrapper class.

With no research of my own I expect a good place to start would be this class:

```
<FieldMapping fieldType="Name Value List">CustomMultiListField</FieldMapping>
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer Mark! But I have another question! As Droplist field takes single item in sitecore but in customItem.config it's wrapper class is CustomMultiListField and taking multiple items. So is it a bug in sitecore or something else?